# Mapping function result set into List of Pojos with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFirstNAvailableSlots(N INTEGER, timestamp_start TIMESTAMP, timestamp_end TIMESTAMP,
cpu INTEGER, max_reservable_cpu INTEGER)
returns TABLE (t_start TIMESTAMP, t_end TIMESTAMP)
```

I would like to call the function, and automatically map the result set into a List of TimeSlots:

```
public class TimeSlot {

    private Timestamp t_start;
    private Timestamp t_end;
}
```

So I added a Query in a repository:

```
public interface WorkstationReservationRepository extends ReservationBaseRepository<WorkstationReservation>{

    @Query(value="SELECT new com.warden.reservationmicroservice.dtos.TimeSlot(t_start,t_end) FROM getFirstNAvailableSlots(:N,:t_start,:t_end,:cpu,:max_reservable_cpu)")
    public List<TimeSlot> getFirstNAvailableSlots(@Param("N")int N, @Param("t_start")Timestamp t_start, @Param("t_end")Timestamp t_end, @Param("cpu") int cpu, @Param("max_reservable_cpu")int max_reservable_cpu);

}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for
> query for method public abstract
> com.warden.reservationmicroservice.dtos.TimeSlot
> com.warden.reservationmicroservice.repositories.WorkstationReservationRepository.getFirstNAvailableSlots(int,java.sql.Timestamp,java.sql.Timestamp,int,int)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:55)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    ... 56 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:104 mismatched input
> '(' expecting {, ',', '.', ID, VERSION, VERSIONED, NATURALID,
> ALL, AND, ANY, AS, ASC, AVG, BETWEEN, BOTH, BY, CASE, CAST, COLLATE,
> COUNT, CROSS, CUBE, CURRENT, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_INSTANT,
> CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATETIME, DAY, DELETE, DESC,
> DISTINCT, ELEMENT, ELEMENTS, ELSE, EMPTY, END, ENTRY, ERROR, ESCAPE,
> EVERY, EXCEPT, EXCLUDE, EXISTS, EXTRACT, FETCH, FILTER, FIRST,
> FOLLOWING, FOR, FORMAT, FROM, FULL, FUNCTION, GROUP, GROUPS, HAVING,
> HOUR, IGNORE, ILIKE, IN, INDEX, INDICES, INNER, INSERT, INSTANT,
> INTERSECT, INTO, IS, JOIN, KEY, LAST, LEADING, LEFT, LIKE, LIMIT,
> LIST, LISTAGG, LOCAL, LOCAL_DATE, LOCAL_DATETIME, LOCAL_TIME, MAP,
> MAX, MAXELEMENT, MAXINDEX, MEMBER, MICROSECOND, MILLISECOND, MIN,
> MINELEMENT, MININDEX, MINUTE, MONTH, NANOSECOND, NEW, NEXT, NO, NOT,
> NULLS, OBJECT, OF, OFFSET, OFFSET_DATETIME, ON, ONLY, OR, ORDER,
> OTHERS, OUTER, OVER, OVERFLOW, OVERLAY, PAD, PARTITION, PERCENT,
> PLACING, POSITION, PRECEDING, QUARTER, RANGE, RESPECT, RIGHT, ROLLUP,
> ROW, ROWS, SECOND, SELECT, SET, SIZE, SOME, SUBSTRING, SUM, THEN,
> TIES, TIME, TIMESTAMP, TIMEZONE_HOUR, TIMEZONE_MINUTE, TRAILING,
> TREAT, TRIM, TRUNCATE, TYPE, UNBOUNDED, UNION, UPDATE, VALUE, VALUES,
> WEEK, WHEN, WHERE, WITH, WITHIN, WITHOUT, YEAR, IDENTIFIER,
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER}    at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:760)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    ... 62 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:104
> mismatched input '(' expecting {, ',', '.', ID, VERSION,
> VERSIONED, NATURALID, ALL, AND, ANY, AS, ASC, AVG, BETWEEN, BOTH, BY,
> CASE, CAST, COLLATE, COUNT, CROSS, CUBE, CURRENT, CURRENT_DATE,
> CURRENT_INSTANT, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATETIME, DAY,
> DELETE, DESC, DISTINCT, ELEMENT, ELEMENTS, ELSE, EMPTY, END, ENTRY,
> ERROR, ESCAPE, EVERY, EXCEPT, EXCLUDE, EXISTS, EXTRACT, FETCH, FILTER,
> FIRST, FOLLOWING, FOR, FORMAT, FROM, FULL, FUNCTION, GROUP, GROUPS,
> HAVING, HOUR, IGNORE, ILIKE, IN, INDEX, INDICES, INNER, INSERT,
> INSTANT, INTERSECT, INTO, IS, JOIN, KEY, LAST, LEADING, LEFT, LIKE,
> LIMIT, LIST, LISTAGG, LOCAL, LOCAL_DATE, LOCAL_DATETIME, LOCAL_TIME,
> MAP, MAX, MAXELEMENT, MAXINDEX, MEMBER, MICROSECOND, MILLISECOND, MIN,
> MINELEMENT, MININDEX, MINUTE, MONTH, NANOSECOND, NEW, NEXT, NO, NOT,
> NULLS, OBJECT, OF, OFFSET, OFFSET_DATETIME, ON, ONLY, OR, ORDER,
> OTHERS, OUTER, OVER, OVERFLOW, OVERLAY, PAD, PARTITION, PERCENT,
> PLACING, POSITION, PRECEDING, QUARTER, RANGE, RESPECT, RIGHT, ROLLUP,
> ROW, ROWS, SECOND, SELECT, SET, SIZE, SOME, SUBSTRING, SUM, THEN,
> TIES, TIME, TIMESTAMP, TIMEZONE_HOUR, TIMEZONE_MINUTE, TRAILING,
> TREAT, TRIM, TRUNCATE, TYPE, UNBOUNDED, UNION, UPDATE, VALUE, VALUES,
> WEEK, WHEN, WHERE, WITH, WITHIN, WITHOUT, YEAR, IDENTIFIER,
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER}    at
> org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:46)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
> ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]   at
> org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:543)
> ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]   at
> org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportInputMismatch(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:327)
> ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]   at
> org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:139)
> ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]   at
> org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.statement(HqlParser.java:343)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:127)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:77)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     ... 69 common frames
> omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Does your `TimeSlot` class define a matching constructor for `t_start` and `t_end`?

Comment: Yes, I use Lombok annotations for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Query` isn’t the correct SQL for calling stored proc, it doesn’t like the `new`, try:

```
@Query(value=“CALL getFirstNAvailableSlots(:N,:t_start,:t_end,:cpu,:max_reservable_cpu)”, nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.warden.reservationmicroservice.repositories.WorkstationReservationRepository.getFirstNAvailableSlots(int,java.sql.Timestamp,java.sql.Timestamp,int,int) and Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'CALL'

Comment: Maybe the @Query needs nativeQuery = true or possibly getFirstNAvailableSlots is not in same schema as db login schema so needs prepending, ie <schema>. getFirstNAvailableSlots. Answer edited.

Comment: Since this is a function and not a stored procedure, you should use `select * from getFirstNAvailableSlots(:N,:t_start,:t_end,:cpu,:max_reservable_cpu)`